# Proving set cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

My question says:

Prove that $(3,6) \cup [10,20)$ has cardinality $\frak{c}$.

Comment: Can you use Schröder–Bernstein theorem?

Comment: Haven't learn that theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can give an explicit bijection of the set with the reals. The idea is to use that

$$\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,0)\cup [0,\infty).$$ Define

$$(-\infty,0)\to (3,6), x\to \frac{6}{e^x+1}$$ and $$[0,\infty) \to [10,20), x \to \frac{20}{e^x+1}.$$

If you prefer a bijection with $(0,1)$ the idea is the same and the bijection is easier to construct. Write $(0,1)=(0,1/2)\cup [1/2,1).$ Now define

$$(0,1/2)\to (3,6),x\to 6x+3,$$

and $$[1/2,1)\to [10,20), x\to 20 x.$$

Comment: I have not learned this theorem, so I have no idea how to apply this.

Comment: I have given a bijection between $(0,1)$ and the set.

Comment: Then you are setting equivalence when you use the equal sign?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest is to say it can't be more than $\mathfrak c$ because it is a subset of $\Bbb R$.  Now if you know $(0,1)$ has cardinality $\mathfrak c$, make a correspondence to $(3,4)$, which is a subset of your set, so your set can't be less than $\mathfrak c$.  You could make an explicit bijection with $(0,1)$ but that would be a little harder.

Comment: Certainly you can.  For example, you can biject $(0,\frac 12)$ with $(3,6)$ with a linear function and $[\frac 12,1)$ and $[10,20)$ with another linear function.  I just thought that was harder than the approach I gave.  My approach also gives you the general statement that any set that is a subset of $\Bbb R$ and a superset of some set of cardinality $\mathfrak c$ has cardinality $\mathfrak c$.  Both approaches work, along with the Schroeder-Bernstein approach.

Comment: Hmm I see, its just that I just learned this and all I really grasped was that a function and (0,1) is involved. Where are you getting the (0, 1/2) from?

Comment: As there are two pieces to the output set, I split the input set so you could make a linear map from each piece.  It was handy that the $[10,20)$ piece was closed on one end.  There is no magic to $\frac 12$.  Any number between $0$ and $1$ would do as well.

Comment: That is what I was doing.  "Need to" is too strong here.  Any bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(3,6) \cup [10,20)$ works.  You just need every point in $(0,1)$ to correspond to exactly one point in  $(3,6) \cup [10,20)$  This was the first that came to my mind because it is rather simple.

Comment: Yes but I mean you are doing this by defining a function?

Comment: Yes.  A bijection is just a function that is onto and one-to-one.  If you find a bijection between two sets, you know they have the same cardinality.  There are other ways to establish that they have the same cardinality, such as my comparisons with $\mathfrak c$.